# Building a new list of Object with combination of other lists of Objects

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have two lists of Client Object:

```
public class Client
{
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DCCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

my list A hold 4 items `ClientID` , and `name` fields are populated, 
My List B Hold the same 4 items but there is no name and hold the `ClientID` `DCCode`, and `CountryName` 
i need to either Update list A `DCCode` and `Countryname` with corresponding values in list B
or create List C which it hold 4 items with complete value of list A and B together 
Like : 
List C L: item 1 : ClientID : 1, Name: XXYY, DCCode :4, CountryName: UK

I can do this using for loop, but i have been trying to use LINQ 
i have tried the following codes but i could not find the correct way to get the result i want 
Solution 1

```
Clients1.Where(i => Clients2.Any(a=> i.CLinetID == a.CLinetID))
```

Solution 2:

```
Clients1.Concat(Clients1).Concat(Clients2).ToList();
```

Any help would be welcomed

Comment: What means you either have to... or ...? What rules decide if you update ListA or insert into ListC?

Comment: I really do not understand the question. It´s quite confusing.

Comment: there is no rule, i can either create list C or update List A

Comment: @L.Guthardt, may be i am not clear enough, i have list a and list b, list a hold part of the client info list b hold other part , these 2 list should create 1 list with all the information they can be linked by client id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have the `ClientID` field populated in both lists join them by that property and project a new object populated with all fields:

```
var result = from c1 in Clients1
             join c2 in Clients2 on c1.ClientID equals c2.ClientID
             select new Client { ClientID = c1.ClientID, Name = c1.Name, DCCode = c2.DCCode, CountryName = c2.CountryName };
```

This will create the third list. You can also update the items of `Clients1` likewise:

```
foreach (var c1 in Clients1)
{
    var c2 = Clients2.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ClientID == c1.ClientID);
    if(c2 != null)
    {
        c1.DCCode = c2.DCCode;
        c1.CountryName = c2.CountryName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gilad, creating the new list helped alot

Comment: @RezaDel - Unless for specific reasons I'd go with the creating a new list option. I feel it is cleaner and more direct.

Answer (score 1):

For updating entities in first list you can create dictionary from second list - that will allow you to quickly find corresponding entity with O(1):

```
var clientsByID = listB.ToDictionary(c => c.ClientID);

foreach(var clientA in listA)
{
    var clientB = clientsByID[clientA.ClientID];
    clientA.DCCode = clientB.DCCode;
    clientA.CountryName = clientB.CountryName;
}
```

You can also join two lists on `ClientID` property and produce new list from results (if enumerable is good for you, then I would go with query syntax instead):

```
var listC = listA.Join(listB, 
                a => a.ClientID, 
                b => b.ClientID,
                (a,b) => new Client { 
                   ClientID = a.ClientID, 
                   Name = a.Name,
                   DCCode = b.DCCode,
                   CountryName = b.CountryName
                }).ToList();
```